# Getting exception when sending email

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp, laravel-mail

Hello everyone I am trying to send an email in Laravel and after using so many configurations and getting same exception each and everytime I am posting here the exception I am getting is.

> Expected response code 220 but got code "", with message ""

Steps I used in configuring Mail in Laravel are following.

I enabled google two steps verification.
 Changed the .env file with the following MAIL variables.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=email@domain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=email_password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

And lastly in my config/mail.php file I change setting like this.

```
return [
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.gmail.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
'from' => ['address' => '<<your email>>', 'name' => '<<any name>>'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
'pretend' => false,
];
```

And here is the function I am using to send email

```
$mail = Mail::raw($msg, function ($message) {
   $message->to('email@domain.com');
});
```

Can anyone guide me that what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you using your real gmail password or an application password from https://security.google.com/settings/security/apppasswords ?

Comment: I am using my real gmail password

Comment: Then use an app password to avoid being prompted for the two-factor validation given that you can't provide the 2nd factor in this context.

Comment: I just generated the app password from the link you gave me and used it instead of the my email password but still getting the same exception

Answer (score 0):

You actually do not need to modify the `config/mail.php` it uses the values from your `.env`. This email config in my `.env` works in my project:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.googlemail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

If you are using gmail you need to get an API password from your google account.

So do following first:

```
 1. Login to your gmail Account
 2. Go to your preferences
 3. Search for Sign In And Security
 4. Sign In to google -> enable two step verification
 5. There you can generate an app password which you have to use in your `.env` file
```

Furthermore be sure to clear you config cache after you changed your `.env` configuration.

Run following command:

`php artisan config:cache`

In your Controller you can use following Schema to sent an email:

First generate a [mailable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mail) class using following command:

```
php artisan make:mail InquirySent
```

The class looks something like this:

```
class InquirySent extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    public function build()
    {
        return $this->view('emails.contacts.inquiry'); // this is the location where you 'style' your view for your mails
    }
}
```

And in your controller you can do following to sent an email.

```
class ContactController extends Controller
{
    protected $myMail;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->myMail = env('MAIL_USERNAME');
    }

    public function sent(ContactRequest $request)
    {
        $data = $request->all();       
        // new implementation using a mailable class
        Mail::to($this->myMail)->send(new InquirySent($data));
    }
}
```

As you can see, you are sending an email to the mail which is set in your `.env` file.

Comment: Now I am getting this exception `Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]`

Comment: @MohsinAbbas did you follow all the steps above? If yes could you tell me that the browser console network message says, thus are you testing this locally or on a productive server?

Comment: sir I have followed each and every step mentioned above which changed the exception and after doing some more research about that new exception I finally got the solution just added these two lines `$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE;
            $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;` and it worked as your answer showed me light so +1 for that Thank you

Comment: I know these lines will loosen up the security but I am using it in my FYP so I don't need security

Comment: @MohsinAbbas I had the issue once that the email functionality did not work on my local windows machine but did work on my productive ubuntu machine so if it does not work in your local machine you could try to run it on a productive ubuntu/linux machine without changing the security (the 2 lines you posted). Good luck! :)

Comment: `$options['ssl']['verify_peer'] = FALSE; $options['ssl']['verify_peer_name'] = FALSE;` Another hint  the 2 lines above or probably related due to the site not using an ssl certificate, so if your site runs on https later on it may work without those lines aswell :)

Comment: Yes you are right and I understand that but already mentioned it that it is just for my FYP nothing more